# No automatic underscore ivar in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-properties, ivar, synthesize

I just noticed that, for some reason, I don't seem to have automatically created underscore iVars in my iOS 7 project, and I wonder why that is. My setup:

**MyClass.h**

```
@property (readonly) NSNumber *aNumber;
```

**MyClass.m**

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (readwrite, strong) NSNumber *aNumber;
@end

@implementation MyClass

(...)

- (NSNumber *)aNumber {
    return _aNumber;
}

- (void)setANumber:(NSNumber *)aNumber {
    _aNumber = aNumber;
}

@end
```

This results in *Use of undeclared identifier: '_aNumber'*.

Why is that so? I thought that underscore iVars are always automatically synthesized? Is it because of the class extension I use? If I put in `@synthesize aNumber = _aNumber;` it (obviously) works.

Comment: the reason is to avoid generate redundant ivar when you don't need it.

Comment: the reason is why not, because you have created a custom getter method, and the auto-synthesize does not create anything for you in that case, you have to do it manually in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one exception to the automatic synthesize rule.

If you override both the getter and the setter of a property then you will have to manually synthesize the property.

This has been the case ever since auto synthesis came in.

Just add the @synthesize line and it will be fine.